# Is it possible to disable array of buttons in anglar 6

Tags: angular6, ionic4

I have array of buttons  `buttons = [1,2,3,4,5,6]` which is diplayed in a row

```
  <ion-row>
   <div *ngFor = "let button of buttons" class="buttons">
     <button ion-button>{{button}}</button>
   </div>
  </ion-row>
```

My requirement is  the array buttons look like stepper  i need

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can , please take a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xbcvu2).

But i advice you to add a dynamic id and name for every button, using index, otherwise you will have a lot of problems